# Can I change how jForm generates HTML for the Form fields?

Tags: jform

Is there a way to manipulate the resulting HTML that jForm generates?

```
$this->form->renderField('myfield');
```

**Apparent Joomla Default Form HTML**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">
        <label id="jform_myfield-lbl" for="jform_myfield" data-placement="bottom">My Field</label>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input name="jform[myfield]" id="jform_myfield" value="My Value" class="input-sm" placeholder="Enter a value" aria-invalid="false" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Preferred HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="myfield" class="col-sm-2 control-label">My Field</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control valid" id="myfield" name="myfield" value="My Value" placeholder="Enter a value" required="" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML markup derives from the following file:

> layouts/joomla/form/renderfield.php

As this is a layout, you can simply create an override for it.
Assuming you're working with a components, copy the file above and paste it in the following directory:

> components/com_EXAMPLE/layouts/joomla/form/renderfield.php

You can then make your changes to this file.

Hope this helps

Comment: That's what I needed....and there's an excellent example at https://medium.com/@n.cramp/how-to-override-the-html-output-of-form-fields-in-joomla-3-ee6f7d9cd580